# Convert string searched with regexp into lowercase with Python

Tags: python, regex, xml

I have some broken XML (the example is not broken, but the document it is) that a part of it looks like this:

```
<sp who="#FERN">
<speaker>FERNANDO</speaker>
<p>Un instante. Soy un hombre. Huir sería cobarde... ¡Sin defenderse! ¡Sin salvarte!... Va a venir... con la vara del guardia. ¡Ay, que ya la conoces! ¡Ah, maldito!... ¡Y me dices que ese hombre es bueno!...</p>
</sp>
```

I want to convert the value of the attribute who into lowercase:

```
<sp who="#fern">
```

Normally I work with the functions \U and \L in regular expressions, but I think this is not supported by python. I tried this regexp:

```
text = re.sub(r'(who="#.*?")', r'\L\1', text)
```

But the output is:

```
<sp \Lwho="#FERN">
```

Which is not what I want... Any help, my dear stackoverflowers? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use anonymous function inside `re.sub`

```
>>> s = '''<sp who="#FERN">
<speaker>FERNANDO</speaker>
<p>Un instante. Soy un hombre. Huir sería cobarde... ¡Sin defenderse! ¡Sin salvarte!... Va a venir... con la vara del guardia. ¡Ay, que ya la conoces! ¡Ah, maldito!... ¡Y me dices que ese hombre es bueno!...</p>
</sp>'''
>>> print re.sub(r'\b(who="#)([^"]*)', lambda m: m.group(1) + m.group(2).lower(), s)
<sp who="#fern">
<speaker>FERNANDO</speaker>
<p>Un instante. Soy un hombre. Huir sería cobarde... ¡Sin defenderse! ¡Sin salvarte!... Va a venir... con la vara del guardia. ¡Ay, que ya la conoces! ¡Ah, maldito!... ¡Y me dices que ese hombre es bueno!...</p>
</sp>
>>>
```

Explanation:

If you want to apply some operations on a captured characters then you must use lambda function in the replacement part of `re.sub`.

- `\b(who="#)` matches thye exact string `who="#` note that `\b` in regex called word boundary which matches between word and non-word chars or vice-versa. And the brackets `(pattern)` used to capture the characters matched by the pattern present inside the brackets. So the first group contains `who="#`
- `([^"]*)` matches any character but not of `"`, zero or more times. So this should capture `FERN`.
- In the replacement part, I just return the first group + lowered second group.

Comment: That is something I didn't know and I don't really understand how it works but it definitely works. I will check it out. Thanks a lot!